# How to get the mean value of the Gaussian basis functions comprising $x$ when solving $Ax=b$ problem?

Tags: optimization, normal-distribution, curves

For the linear equation
$$
Ax=b,
$$
where $A$ is a 100 x 64 matrix, $b$ is a 100 x 1 vector, $x$ is a 64 x 1 vector, unknown.
In my situation, x consists of no more than 5 Gaussian basis.
$$
x=\Sigma_{i=1}^5 F_i \exp\left(-\frac{(T-T \mathrm{mean}_i)^2}{W_i}\right)
$$
Here T is a known 64 x 1 vector, $W_i$ controls the width of the distribution and $F_i$ is the amplitude of the Gaussian basis. $F_i$, $W_i$ and $T\mathrm{mean}_i$ are undetermined parameters.

$A$,$b$,$T$ are attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4YGsBUhgXqq_RQnniA76cY1o65NL59i/view?usp=sharing).

What I am interested in is the $T\mathrm{mean}_i$, i.e. the number of Gaussian basis and the center of the existing Gaussian ($A_i>0$).

Comment: This is a non linear optimization problem.

Comment: Cannot be solved by gradient-based optimization algorithms? @Royi

Comment: The function is smooth, so you can do gradient descent. But the convergence is to a local minima, not the global one.